# New project Error - Product Targets Turn Red

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]Every time I create a new project, all of the product targets turn red immediately. If I understand correctly, that means that it can't locate the folder it is in. I have tried restarting Xcode, clean, clean build, and restarting my computer. Is this just how its supposed to be or is there something wrong with my targets?

[image: When]

When I go and right click on the app target and "Show in Finder", it takes me to the Derived Data folder and not the actual app which is the picture above:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the targets but the products that are marked as red.

The products do not exist after creating a new project as they have not been build yet and thus they are marked red. Building means "creating a product".

After you build the project once, the product/artefact exists and is not marked red any more.

Comment: That was my first thought but didn't work. Still red.

Comment: `Gradebook.app` shoud be black after building. If it is not, please update the question with more information what you have tried and what happened. I have tried this for you. Create virgin project -> red, build -> black.

Comment: I have built again and created another project to see if it was project specific. All three targets stay red after build and run.

Comment: Try to: rightClick on the red target.app -> show in Finder after building. Does it show the .app in Finder?

Comment: When I do that it takes me to the derived data folder and not the actual app. I put a pic above.

Comment: This _is_ the app.

Comment: So why would it still be red?

Comment: I do not know. It works fine here. As the app is build correctly, I would recommend to ignore the red color.